# How do I specify a regex of certain length where I want to disallow characters instead of allowing them?

Tags: regex, validation

I need a regular expression which will validate a string to have length 7 and doesn't contain vowels, number 0 and number 1.

I know about character classes like `[a-z]`  but it seems a pain to have to specify every possibility that way: `[2-9~!@#$%^&*()b-df-hj-np-t...]`

For example:

- If I pass a String `June2013` - it should fail because length of the string is 8 and it contains 2 vowels and number 0 and 1.
- If I pass a String `XYZ2003` - it should fail because it contains 0.
- If I pass a String `XYZ2223` - it should pass.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

So that would be something like this:

```
^[^aeiouAEIOU01]{7}$
```

The `^$` anchors ensure there's nothing in there but what you specify, the character class `[^...]` means any character except those listed and the `{7}` means exactly seven of them.

That's following the English definition of vowel, other cultures may have a different idea as to what constitutes voweliness.

Based on your test data, the results are:

```
pax> echo 'June2013' | egrep '^[^aeiouAEIOU01]{7}$'
pax> echo 'XYZ2003' | egrep '^[^aeiouAEIOU01]{7}$'
pax> echo 'XYZ2223' | egrep '^[^aeiouAEIOU01]{7}$'
XYZ2223
```

Comment: Thanks a ton. It was kind of urgent and as I don't have any exp on regex so thought of posting here. Meanwhile I was also trying out to develop at my end too. I got the same as well - ^[^0-1aeiouAEIOU]{7}$

Answer (score 0):

This is the briefest way to express it:

```
(?i)^[^aeiou01]{7}$
```

The term `(?i)` means "ignore case", which obviates typing both upper and lower vowels.